# Casting the sum of some variables to a pointer and then to an integer again

Tags: c, pointers, casting

So, I've encountered a strange line in the code I'm reading and I'm not sure why it is cast the way it is.

The code (I've put the declarations etc. in that are relevant for clarity, also, as you probably guessed, UINT1 is a 1 byte unsigned integer and INT2 is a 2 byte signed integer):

```
#define Z 2
INT2 t;
UINT1 *x; //sent into the function as a pointer as in f( UINT1 *x )
INT2 y = 20; //declared as 0 first then some number is assigned (let's say 20)
t = (INT2) *(INT2 *) (x + y + Z);
```

What I don't understand is, why use this overly complex way of casting it when one of these should work just as well:

```
t = (INT2) (x + y + Z);
t = (INT2) *(x + y + Z);
```

What could be the reason for doing this? I'm relatively new to C and I'm probably missing something.

Comment: `t = (INT2) *(INT2 *) (x + y + Z);` is not just a cast, the first asterisk dereferences the pointer. Your version would convert a pointer value to an integer, that's most of the time quite meaningless. (Without seeing the original code, this looks very dirty, violating the strict-aliasing rule.)

Comment: This code looks highly suspicious.

Comment: @FelixPalmen yeah it's a huge company's code so I can't really share much without breaking some sort of confidentiality agreement. I'm just looking if there could be *any* reason for doing this. Oh, to make matters even stranger, this resulting value is sent into a function that changes it from little endian to big endian (or vice versa). (I'm working on arm devices btw)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Given the declaration of `x`, which appears equivalent to `unsigned char *`, there shouldn't be a strict aliasing violation.  Whether there's an alignment issue is another story.

Comment: @JohnHamilton That's unfortunate that "huge companies" are having such a low quality and likely buggy code in their products. Do you guys have a code review process?

Comment: x is a pointer to something, and I guess y and z combine to make an offset from the pointer.

Comment: @dbush it's not allowed to alias an array of `char` with something else -- only the other way around. So this code would only be valid if whatever `x` points to actually contains objects of type `INT2`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's not our code but it could very well be, we bought the code from a huge company (ours is tiny in comparison) and I'm working hard on getting our company to have some sort of code review process.

Comment: @JohnHamilton the second "simplified" form does something different as well ... as the type of `x` is `UINT1 *`, dereferencing `(x+y+Z)` just reads an `UINT1` (**one** byte) which is then converted to `INT2`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen wow you're fast. I was just commenting on your answer to let you know. Thanks for all your help btw, I'll pick your answer if there are no others on Monday at the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some context, it's unclear what exactly this code does, but this line:

```
t = (INT2) *(INT2 *) (x + y + Z);
```

does some pointer arithmetics on `x`, then casts the result to a *pointer to `INT2`* (probably violating strict aliasing btw.) and dereferences it.

The result of the dereference is then cast again to `INT2` -- this part is redundant, dereferencing an `INT2 *` already gives an `INT2`, so it could just read:

```
t = *(INT2 *)(x + y + Z);
```

---

Your "simplified" version on the other hand:

```
t = (INT2) (x + y + Z);
```

does something **completely** different and utterly meaningless: The resulting address of the pointer arithmetics on `x` is converted to an `INT2` in this line.

Comment: Oh so it alters pointer x's position then? As in, if it read from 0xF0 and we added 10 to it, it would now read from 0xFA?

Comment: @JohnHamilton it doesn't touch `x`, but apart from that, yes, it reads from a different position. Looks like reinvented array indexing.

Comment: Thank you! That actually helps me resolve a few things in this huge code :D

Comment: I've modified the question, added `t = (INT2) *(x + y + Z);` too and didn't delete the previous one so as to not interfere too much with your answer. Wouldn't that work as well as your suggested line? (also adding t's declaration now)

Comment: @JohnHamilton see my comment on your question. No, it wouldn't work, it reads just **one** byte (as opposed to the two bytes read by the original code)